# Unix/Linux command to view available servers

Tags: unix-shell

Situation: I'm inspired to work from home this evening. So I download some source from work's svn repo. Unfortunately, I find some lib files are missing. Not a problem, I'll remote in to my desktop at work and check out the environment there and see what I'm missing. Only windows-7 sucks at authentication and won't let me log in. However, I was able to access my file system via a share I have set up by remoting into a win-xp box on our network.

So if I could find a windows xp box on my network, I could use that to view my files at work. I can putty in to a server on the network, but it's a unix box. If I could see a list of servers that are up, I could easily pick one I know is windows and move forward.

What command can I type into the shell prompt to give me a list of available servers?

Comment: It would greatly help to know what OS or distribution is running on your server.

Comment: So, do you want the equivalent of *Network Neighborhood*?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a question about windows 7 authentication as well.  In my experience windows 7 works great.

Comment: @Cristian basically. @Zoredache Well, I locked my machine's logins down. But for some reason didn't lock down samba shares...

Comment: @Weboide I was operating under the assumption that a common command like this would/should be available under about any distro. It's CentOS 4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk about remoting can we assume you are speaking about connecting via RDP?

If you wanted to see a list of computers that are up and have port 3389 open you could use a nmap command like this: `nmap -p 3389 10.2.27.0/24`.

Comment: Zored, after about 5 minutes, it yields no response. I narrowed it down to 10.15.0.0/16 being that I can be sure it's under that mask.

Comment: Unfortunately the default config of Windows Firewall disables ICMP; try `nmap -PN -p 3389 10.15.0.0/16`, or `arp -n` to see what the host has recently made contact with (then a straight `arp` to resolve hostnames).

Comment: I finally ended up changing the settings on my remote desktop and managed to get in. Apparently it was assigning a domain to my username when trying to authenticate. I had to delete that and simply use my username and it worked. I appreciate both responses, and will upvote for your help, although I can't accept either since I'm not actually running them.

Answer (score 1):

What's your DHCP server (assuming you're not running static IPs) and can you get the list of leases? `arp` might also show you the list of "active" machines on your network, if they've had recent contact with the host you run it on.